# Sharepoint modal dialog from external site

Tags: javascript, html, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have a Microsoft Sharepoint 2010 installation and when I search items with the integrated search, I see that the results have the following javascript call:

```
<a id="SRB_g_b60c4a68_5348_49ec_846c_b9d069d6774d_1_Title" href="javascript:openDialogSearch('https://example.com/xyz/DispForm.aspx?ID=1');" title="This is just a test"><strong>Test</strong></a>
```

Now I need to call the same call js function (*openDialogSearch*) from an external site in the same intranet.

I've seen that this funcion is defined in a inpage script which calls the following function passing the url of the resource:

```
SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(url)
```

How could I call the same function from an external HTML page not inside Sharepoint?

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend trying to recreate the dialog infrastructure from SP:

Instead, use a dialog like jQuery dialog:
    https://jqueryui.com/dialog/

You'll need to change this code to access your SP URL.

You'll also have a configuration change.  You'll need to allow access to SP from your URL, otherwise, you'll get Access-Control-Allow-Origin errors.  That's an update to the SP web.config file for the given site collection.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Dialog - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://jqueryui.com/dialog/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $("#dialog").load("PUT YOUR URL HERE").dialog({modal:true});
    //$("#dialog").dialog();
  } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
  <p>This is the default dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.</p>
</div>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Ctznkane55, but I need to replicate the exact behavior of the Sharepoint dialog, because it's also filtering some contents. Also, I would like to know why you don't recommend to recreate the infrastructure from SP. Thanks.